# I need to insert a text above the line containing a particular string "[TOP]" in batch programming

Tags: string, batch-file, text, insert, find

E.g. the file `abc.txt` contains below text in it and i have to add text "infra" in it above [TOP]:

```
;plcd
;abcd
valueof=a,b,c
[TOP]
```

and the output should be like this:

```
;plcd
;abcd
valueof=a,b,c
infra
[TOP]
```

How to do this in batch programming.

Comment: & what have you tried so far?

Comment: `sed` is not a standard install on Windows, but with the right tool, this kind of problem is trivial.

Comment: I am new to batch programming shaktimaan..need help in this :(

Comment: SO is _not_ a newbie-farm.

Comment: Don't be angry dude..if it's easy to answer for you then it would be a great help to me then otherwise leave it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal

    set "file=abc.txt"

    set "start="
    for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=  %%a in ("%file%") do (
        if not defined start set "start=1" & break > "%file%"
        if "%%~a"=="[TOP]" (>>"%file%" echo(infra)
        >>"%file%" echo(%%a
    )
```

For each line with data in the file, if it contains `[TOP]`, echo `infra`. After it, echo the readed line.